# Iframe load event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am using google drive in iframe like this

```js
//than i am calling it like

jQuery('#myframeid').load(function() {
  alert("loaded");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="myframeid" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://xxx/yy/google-drive" style="display:block; width:100%;" height="724px">
    </iframe>
```

but no luck.

Comment: See your snippet .its working ..I think you are missed jquery library

Comment: I am using jquery library, there is some conflict on my page